Could nuclear weapons been developed without appreciating $E=mc^2$?
EDIT: The question was closed due to being opinion-based, so let me explain what I am asking:
It often happens that there is a theorem that gives insight and simplifies the calculations, but it is not actually required to derive the physical behavior. Example: The Equipartition theorem can sometimes be used to calculate the average energy of a system without needing to perform explicit intergrals; but if we didn't know about this theorem, we could still calculate this energy.
I wonder whether $E=mc^2$ is a similar case, for example in the context of nuclear bombs. The two are very often linked. For example, here is a quote from the Wikipedia article on Mass–energy equivalence:

Such conversions between types of energy happen in nuclear weapons, in which the protons and neutrons in atomic nuclei lose a small fraction of their original mass, though the mass lost is not due to the destruction of any smaller constituents. Nuclear fission allows a tiny fraction of the energy associated with the mass to be converted into usable energy such as radiation; in the decay of the uranium, for instance, about 0.1% of the mass of the original atom is lost.

I can imagine that an easy way to calculate the emmited energy is to just calculate $E=mc^2$ before and after the fission, and take the difference;  And I imagine there is an alternative way, which is to do explicit calculations of the state transitions in the nuclear process. The question is whether this is true, and whether this alternative way still requires explicit usage of $E=mc^2$.
Below is the original question.

In a world where special relativity was never discovered, and in particular $E=mc^2$ was not known: would nuclear physics and engineering be blocked from progress? in particular, would nuclear weapons not been developed or understood?
This is not a question about a hypothetical world, it's about trying to understand whether  $E=mc^2$ is really necessary, or are there alternative methods to calculate the energy released in, e.g., nuclear fusion, perhaps methods that account for all microscopic nuclear forces.

Hypotheticals are basically impossible to answer definitively. Maybe they would treat it as stamp collecting and having a gigantic unexplained table of results, and that would be sufficient to continue working enough to get a bomb going. Who knows what kind of insanity people could tolerate?

This is a question impossible to answer in a non-opinion based and scientific way. We can't know what would happen if the history was different.

This could maybe be a question for the History of Science SE site.

FWIW: $E=mc^2$ is no less pertinent to the question of how a candle flame works than it is to the question of how a nuclear power station works.  In both cases, there is a mass defect in the reaction products that matches the amount of energy that was released. If it's conceivable that humankind could have discovered candles without knowing $E=mc^2$, then it is equally conceivable that we could have discovered nuclear chain reactions without knowing it. *But,* The early nuclear physicists were gobsmacked by the amount of energy released in each fission event. The question was...

@naturallyInconsistent, Ruffolo: the original question explicitly mentioned this is not a hypothetical. But I edited it now.

...how could they hope to convince their peers that the result was real? How could they continue to obtain funding for their research instead of being dismissed as cranks? That was when Lise Meitner recalled Einstein's formula, and when she looked up the masses of fission products, she discovered a mass defect that was exactly equal to the energy that was released. That was reassuring. In theory, you could design working nuclear reactors without Einstein. But in a world where science is done by human beings with all their personal faults...? That's where it becomes a matter of opinion.

By their own admission the understanding of the mass defect helped Meitner and Frisch to correctly understand the nuclear fission experiments results and for everyobe to appreciate it as a source of enormous energy. However could nuclear weaponry been developed without the development of special relativity? I would say yes, just on the basis of the experimental data after more experiments one would understand the potential and know what to do to make a fission bomb.
E.g. most of the stuff in the Manhattan project required to produce the Little Boy was not some intricate nuclear physics. It as just the development of uranium enrichnment technologies required to produce enough quantities of highly enriched uranium.
However to even conceive fusion reactions you need to understand special relativity AND quantum mechanics. So it's hard for me to conceive such scenario. Even if fusion was understood more from experimental side somehow before the theoretical advances it would cause a revolution in physics by itself
